# After executing the last line i get following error: ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (4457, 2) instead

Tags: python, nlp, spyder, naivebayes

```
y = pd.get_dummies(messages['label'])
y = y.iloc[:,1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20,random_state = 0)


from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
spam_detect_model = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = spam_detect_model.predict(y_test)
```

<after this getting this error ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (4457, 2) instead.>

Comment: Welcome to SO ;)
The problem is due to this line `y_pred = spam_detect_model.predict(y_test)`. You must pass the `X_test` instead of `y_test` (as argument)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, directly under your `y` variable, do this to convert it to integer:

```py
y = y.apply(lambda x: x.argmax(), axis=1).values
```

And `y_pred = spam_detect_model.predict(X_test)` not `y_test`.